# Hadoop Jobs statistics using YARN Resource Manager REST API + elasticsearch +Kibana

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hadoop-yarn, kibana, hadoop2

My goal is to provide Hadoop jobs statistics web UI for administrative users.

I use HortonWorks Hadoop2 cluster and jobs run on YARN.

From the architecture perspective , I am planning to collect jobs related information ( such as start time, end time, mappers, etc ) from [YARN Resource Manager REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API) as scheduled cron job >>  index them in to elastic search >> show them in Kibana.

I wonder if there is better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Ambari? It provides metrics, dashboards, and alerting without having to create the framework from scratch. 
[Apache Ambari](https://ambari.apache.org)

Comment: Ambari is more of Monitoring tool. I don't think , it is useful for job statistics. For eg: I want to see job execution pattern of a Hadoop job for the last month.  Please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: Historically, for sure. However, I've been told the vision for Ambari is to even include functionality currently in Hue (like running Hive and Pig queries). I only say that to point out that it's growing and has grown. I believe Hive queries are in the latest release. All that job data is persisted in HDFS and Ambari has the ability to present data in custom views. I could see someone w/a use case to build out reporting, alerting on a particular job or job stream. Is it the best for your situation? Maybe not. Just mentioning it because it's more powerful and extensible than commonly believed.

Comment: Sorry, the character limit is killing me. Took 3 swings at it.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari provides statistics on an infrastructure level not on job level. So, you need to write a custom code to use yarn-rest API which provides you a JSON response. Based on which you can use the JSON parser and get the exact details. I have written one on python, you can refer to this link-[https://dzone.com/articles/customized-alerts-for-hadoop-jobs-using-yarn-rest](http://thelearnguru.com/customized-alerts-for-hadoop-jobs-using-yarn-rest-api/)

http://thelearnguru.com/customized-alerts-for-hadoop-jobs-using-yarn-rest-api